# Get Specific Data from Excel using Pandas and Convert Everything into a String as well as NaN

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have an excel file with the 1st row always empty.
The 2nd row with data I don't need.
The 3rd row is always a header and the following rows are always data with `Total` being under `Title_3` and `Title_4`.

I read the files using `pandas`. I've attached the output of the result.

My goal is that I want everything in the array to be a string as well as nan. How can I replace the nan with a string and have the output display like this:

## Goal Output

```
['nan', 'Title_1', 'RED_100', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', '10', 'nan']
['nan', 'Title_2', 'GREEN_200', '2018-02-02 00:00:00', '20', 'nan']
['nan', 'Title_3', 'RED_300', '2019-11-15 00:00:00', '30', 'Total']
['123456', 'Title_4', 'YELLOW_100', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', '40', '100']
```

## Code

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

path = r'C:\Temp Files\Excel_2.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])

#df.drop(df.head(2).index, inplace=True)

print(df)
res = (df.dropna(how='all') #remove completely empty rows
.dropna(how='all',axis=1) #remove completely empty columns
.T #flip columns into row position
#convert to list    
.to_numpy()
.tolist()
)

print()
Title_1 = res[1]
print(Title_1)
```

## Output

```
            Unnamed: 0           Unnamed: 1           Unnamed: 2           Unnamed: 3
0                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN               123456
1              Title_1              Title_2              Title_3              Title_4
2              RED_100            GREEN_200              RED_300           YELLOW_100
3  2019-01-01 00:00:00  2018-02-02 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00  2019-01-01 00:00:00
4                   10                   20                   30                   40
5                  NaN                  NaN                Total                  100

[nan, 'Title_2', 'GREEN_200', '2018-02-02 00:00:00', '20', nan]
```

## My Excel File

[image]

## Data I Need

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#add skiprows=1, nrows=6
df = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=str, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], skiprows=1, nrows=6)

#transpose the df
df_transposed = df.T

#transform all entries to strings (including nan)
df_transposed = df_transposed.applymap(str)
```

You already put effort into providing info for the question but it would have been really helpful if you had also provided a test dataframe like this: df = pd.DataFrame(data=...
The Code is therefore untested!